# react native shadows ios

Tags: react-native, shadow, effect

I have a component with following styles

```
 shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 4 },
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      // overflow: 'visible',
      borderRadius: 5,
```

but it's given me shadows for all elements inside a container. How to apply shadows only for container (Card) itself?

[image]

Comment: Share code where you have applied above style to component !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give the container a `backgroundColor:'white'` for example

```
container:{
  backgroundColor:'white',
  borderRadius: 5,
  ...Platform.select({
     ios: {
       shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 4 },
       shadowColor: Colors.grey,
       shadowOpacity: 0.5,
       shadowRadius: 2,
       // overflow: 'visible',
      },
     android: {
       elevation: 4
     },
    })
}
```